# Roles management with no provider?

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-membership, roleprovider

In my app I need to check the roles for the loggind user to determine if the user could see some controls or not

first I use the loginview template from MS but as I don't have the users db neither the roles db
So I couldn't add a role provider so I couldn't use the Role class to check the users\role

As in my case I have a session with user info and the roles he has,and I need to perform a check on those roles to set which control will be enable to user but with standard way "using .net built in class or code"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to use parts of the asp.net membership/authentication/authorisation services you'll need to implement a custom role provider to perform role membership checking.

The first thing to do is create a class that inherits from `System.Web.Security.RoleProvider`, in which it sounds like the methods you'll initially care about implementing are:

- FindUsersInRole
- GetRolesForUser
- GetUsersInRole
- IsUserInRole

So, you'll end up with something similar to:

```
using System; 
using System.Collections.Generic; 
using System.Linq; 
using System.Web; 
using System.Web.Security;

public class MyCustomRoleProvider : RoleProvider
{
    public override string[] FindUsersInRole(string roleName, string usernameToMatch)
    {
    }

    public override string[] GetRolesForUser(string username)
    {
    }

    public override string[] GetUsersInRole(string roleName)
    {
    }

    public override bool IsUserInRole(string username, string roleName)
    {
        return GetUsersInRole(roleName).Contains(username);
    }
}
```

*Note: Visual Studio will show a lot of methods, such as `GetAllRoles` with a `throws new NotImplementedException()`, but I've written a "bare minimum" role provider previously and only needed to implement the methods I've listed above. That was for "read only" roles where the web app didn't update them though.*

You'll then need to add the `roleManager` element to your `web.config` file under `system.web` as follows:

```
<roleManager defaultProvider="NameOfYourRoleProvider" enabled="true">
    <providers>
        <clear />
         <add name="NameOfYourRoleProvider" type="Namespace.To.Your.Class.And.Class.Name, Name.Of.Assembly.Containing.Your.RoleProvider" />
    </providers>
</roleManager>
```

One thing to bear in mind is that the `RoleProvider` instance is created by the underlying asp.net infrastructure so you'll need to access the session data by going via `HttpContext.Current.Session` (and checking that `HttpContext.Current` isn't null prior to using it), which will require a `using System.Web;` in the code for your provider.

Answer (score 4):

Your question isn't overly clear, but if you want to provide your own logic for deciding what roles a user belongs to, then you can do that as follows:

Fill in the two methods below using your own custom logic:

```
public class MyRoleProvider : System.Web.Security.RoleProvider
{
    public override string[] GetRolesForUser(string username)
    {
          // check a database or an xml file etc.
    }

    public override bool IsUserInRole(string username, string roleName)
    {
         // check a database or an xml file etc.
    }    
}
```

Then, add the following to your web.config:

```
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="MyRoleProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="MyRoleProvider" type="MyNameSpace.MyRoleProvider, MyProjectOrAssemblyName" />
  </providers>
</roleManager>
```

(replacing values according to their name)